# Using newly added firewall service in rpm spec script fails

Tags: rpm-spec, firewalld

I have a rpm package that adds a new firewall service and during install wants to enable this service. However this fails with *"Error: INVALID_SERVICE"*:

```
$ dnf localinstall -y firewall-spec-test-0.0.1-1.fc35.x86_64.rpm
Last metadata expiration check: 1:29:06 ago on Fri 27 May 2022 01:20:48 CEST.
Dependencies resolved.
==============================================================================
 Package                Arch       Version             Repository        Size
==============================================================================
Installing:
 firewall-spec-test     x86_64     0.0.1-1.fc35        @commandline     7.2 k

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total size: 7.2 k
Installed size: 164  
Downloading Packages:
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                      1/1 
  Installing       : firewall-spec-test-0.0.1-1.fc35.x86_64               1/1 
  Running scriptlet: firewall-spec-test-0.0.1-1.fc35.x86_64               1/1 
Error: INVALID_SERVICE: 'dummy' not among existing services

  Verifying        : firewall-spec-test-0.0.1-1.fc35.x86_64               1/1 

Installed:
  firewall-spec-test-0.0.1-1.fc35.x86_64                                      

Complete!
```

The dummy.xml file is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <description>dummy service</description>
  <short>dummy</short>
  <port port="1234" protocol="udp"/>
</service>
```

and the spec file I have trimmed down to for testing is:

```
Name:           firewall-spec-test
Version:        0.0.1
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        ...
License:        GPLv3
URL:            https://stackoverflow.com/q/...
Source0:        dummy.xml
BuildRequires:  systemd-rpm-macros
Requires:       firewalld

%description
...

%prep
cp %{SOURCE0} .

%build

%install
mkdir -p ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_sysconfdir}/firewalld/services
cp -a dummy.xml ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}%{_sysconfdir}/firewalld/services

# https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#_syntax
%post
if [ $1 == 1 ]
then
    # First time install
    firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=dummy
    firewall-cmd --reload --quiet
fi
exit 0

%preun
if [ $1 == 0 ]
then
    # Complete uninstall
    firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --remove-service=dummy
    firewall-cmd --reload --quiet
fi
exit 0

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%config(noreplace) %{_sysconfdir}/firewalld/services/*

%changelog
...
```

So how do I get firewall to use the new service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently firewalld needs an initial reload first in order for it to pick up the added service definition.

```
--- firewall-spec-test.spec.fail        2022-05-27 02:58:34.747351419 +0200
+++ firewall-spec-test.spec     2022-05-27 02:59:13.925280222 +0200
@@ -25,6 +25,7 @@
 if [ $1 == 1 ]
 then
        # First time install
+       firewall-cmd --reload --quiet  # In order for firewall-cmd to pick up the added service file
        firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=dummy
        firewall-cmd --reload --quiet
 fi
```